# Are questions about pyramid schemes and other scams off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

We have the following question on our site about a possible pyramid scheme:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/232/multi-level-marketing-and-pyramid-schemes-how-to-recognise-pyramid-scheme-masque

Should we consider questions about pyramid schemes and other financial frauds on-topic or off-topic here?

Comment: It was my question. I guess I didn't paid enough ettention to definition "Skeptics is aimed at *applied* skepticism -- researching specific areas of _woo or pseudoscience_"<br>. I would agree - it's not about pseudosience. But I would argue it can't be discussed as sceptic topic in general.

Comment: Note that [money.se] is a much better place to ask. [There are currently 113 questions with the tag 'scams' there](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scams). I assume the audience there is more knowledgable in these matters too.

Answer (score 2):

I think that questions about *specific* scams should be on-topic. We are already in the business of exposing scams, in a way, and we would do the Internet a great service by exposing those, that much is sure.

With that said, the question you link to is just too broad to be useful. I'd even argue it's off-topic because it's no longer about skepticism and is rather about law.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the second paragraph? The question appears to me to be about one particular scam, and unrelated to the law.

Comment: @Fabian There I wasn't sure what to do. I had example of particular scam, but can I reveal the name of the company/network? Especially as they don't seem have problems with law. As main question itself - I didn't thought it is too broad as I expected kind of list of attributes whitch may show it is scam.